# php ajax get previous class data

Tags: php, ajax, class, extend

I created a plugin that allows to set a query an then retrieve some post inside a loop thanks to this query.

I would like to implement an ajax button in order to load more posts.
My aim is to get the previous $data set in class in ajax. It will have multi class instance on a same page.

What is the right way to do this kind of thing?

Here my code:

```
class class_name {

    protected $data;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->data = $this->get_data($name);
        $this->show();  
    }

    public function get_data($name) {
        $info = get_page_by_title($name);
        $id   = $info->ID;
        $meta_keys = get_post_custom_keys($id);
        if (empty($meta_keys)) {
            return;
        }
        foreach ($meta_keys as $meta_key) {
            $meta_values = get_post_custom_values($meta_key, $id);
            if (strrpos($meta_key, $this->plugin_slug) !== false) {
                foreach ($meta_values as $meta_value) {
                    $meta_value = maybe_unserialize($meta_value);
                    $data[$name][$meta_key] = $meta_value;
                }
            }
        }
        return $data[$name];
    }

    public function show() {        
        $this->loop();
    }

    public function loop() {
        $query_args = $data[$name];
        query_posts($query_args);
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            $output  = the_title();
            echo $output;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();

    }

}

add_action('wp_ajax_load_more', array(class_name_ajax, 'load_more'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more', array(class_name_ajax, 'load_more'));

class class_name_ajax extends class_name {

    protected $data;

    public function load_more() {

        $nonce = $_POST['ajax_nonce']; 

        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'ajax_nonce' ) ) {
            die ();
        } else {
            // $this undefined
            parent::loop(); // I woould like to loop with the data set for current name
        }
        die();
    }

}

new class_name('name1');
new class_name('name2');
```

The ajax request works fine but I can't get the previous.

**EDIT:**

Maybe, it will be simple if i set a global var in my class_name and then retrieve it my class_name_ajax in ajax? But how can I pass a varibale set in a class to another class retieve with ajax (without javascript)?